# For loop only reads the last line of the text file

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a simple login program where I need user to input the correct details to proceed
,This is my code:

```
email_l = []
pass_l = []
f = open("lab6.txt", "r")
content = f.readlines()
print(content)
for line in content:
    s = line.rstrip()
    name,email,password,cn,dob,citi,emergency,creditcardnum,creditcardexp,points = s.split(",")
    email_l = email
    pass_l = password
usergmail = input("enter gmail:")
if usergmail in email_l:
    passcode = input("enter password:")
    if passcode in pass_l:
        print("Login successful! Welcome",name)
        display_user()
    else:
        print("Wrong Password!")
else:
    print("wrong gmail")
```

and this is what contained in the text file

```
JunYing,jy654@gmail.com,654321,0125489875,12/05/2001,Malaysian,0175987865,2546 4587 5895 5423,21/28,762
john,ok@gmail.com,123456,0165784399,17/7/2003,Malaysian,0124758995,5874 4585 4569 4214,09/25,547
Pepe,tsy@gmail.com,123598,02654898,8/02/2011,American,02165897,5896 4578 5215 4512,07/25,541
```

I found out it only reads the last line of the file but I'm using a for loop shouldn't it be reading every line in the file?
How can I make it to read every line in the file and make every email that entered into the input is matched with the file.
Due to some rules, only Array can be utilized in the assignment so I can only use array

Comment: It's reading every line, but the variables you assign the line to (e.g. `email_l`, `pass_l` are getting overwritten with each iteration. Since they're lists, you should be using `.append()`, rather than assigning using `=`

Comment: If I wrote `a = 1` and then `a = 2`, would you be surprised that `a` is only equal to 2, and is not also equal to 1?

Comment: I get the Idea of .append but how can I use it could u show me an example of code?

Comment: You'll find an example for [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) in the chapter about lists in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `email_l.append(email)` instead of just over writing it since it is a Python List.

Answer (score 0):

Your list variables  "email_l" and "pass_l" are overwritten in each loop iteration.

you have to use:

email_l.append(email)

pass_l.append(password)

in order for your code to work.

refer to python data structures documentation to learn more

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Take care "display_user()" function is not defined in your communicated code. This will raise undefined function errors.